# Event is not Called C#

Tags: c#, lambda, event-handling

I'm currently into making a NFC Library, where i need to raise an Event, when a Card has successfully been read.

In my MainProject i call the library like this:

```
reader = new NfcReader();
    if (reader.Initialize())
    {
        reader.UidReceived += (s, args) => 
            DisplayText(String.Format("UID received: {0}", args.Uid));
    }
```

My Library:

```
public class NfcReader
{
    private SCardMonitor monitor;
    public event EventHandler<NfcReaderEventArgs> UidReceived;

    public bool Initialize()
    {
        // When a card is inserted, an event is raised
        // then I want to read the Uid of the card 
        monitor = new SCardMonitor(new SCardContext(), SCardScope.System);
        monitor.CardInserted += (s,a) => GetUid(a.ReaderName);
        return true;
    }

    private void GetUid(string readerName)
    {
        string uid = MyUidGetter(readerName);
        OnUidReceived(uid);
    }

    private void OnUidReceived(string uid)
    {
        var handler = UidReceived;
        if (handler == null)
        {
            handler(this, new NfcReaderEventArgs(uid));
        }
    }
}
```

The debugger steps through `handler(this, new NfcReaderEventArgs(uid));`, but the `DisplayText` method doesn't get called. Any ideas?

Comment: `handler == null` is clearly a mistake (typo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is an typo that you check for handler to be null? ;)

Maybe your Initialize does return false. And the debugger steps through exactly because it won't call anything. That is made sure by the if.

I recommend you use handler != null instead and make sure Initialize returns true.

Comment: Ooops... that's it. Okay time for a coffee break I guess ^^

Comment: Yeah ! typos happen all the time und are easy to overlook.